# C# code never gets hit (hang) when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I'm implementing an AJAX service that kicks off long-running process and gets the status via Javascript's setInterval.  The full code is here http://blog.robseder.com/2013/10/18/executing-a-long-running-process-from-a-web-page/

AjaxServices.asmx creates a new static instance of my worker class.  Worker class updates its progress.  The problem is everything is working as it should locally.  But it hangs and never proceeds past the line when deployed to server.  I'm using IIS 7.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string))
using(SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    //...
    if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open()
}
```

AjaxServices.asmx/GetStatus works fine... It returns the status circled below (HTTP 200).  The problem is it doesn't hit my Sql code, or the try-catch block at all.

[image]

**Worker Class code excerpt**

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    UpdatePercent(6, 7, "Starting (inside USING)...", runId);

    #region first step
    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "[dbo].[sp name]";

        //parameters... etc...

        UpdatePercent(7, 8, "Parameters added, connection state: " + connectionState, runId);

        //code doesn't proceed past this line
        if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Open();

        UpdatePercent(5, 10, "about to enter try-catch...", runId);

        try
        {
            UpdatePercent(5, 10, "Starting run insertion...", runId);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            runId = int.Parse(command.Parameters["@RunID"].Value.ToString());
            UpdatePercent(10, 15, "Inserted run dimension...", runId);
        }
        catch(SqlException exc)
        {
            UpdatePercent(100, 100, exc.Message, runId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the connection is initially closed, what is supposed to open it? That if would be false as the state is closed.

Comment: Does it hang, or is an exception being thrown? My gut would say it's the latter.

Comment: @JBKing Sorry, I meant `conn.State != Open`...  @Michael Gunter, it hangs.  Otherwise my `catch` block would `UpdatePercent` appropriately.

Comment: Have you tried expanding your try/catch block? Perhaps there is a timeout in the conn.Open happening? IOW, what if it isn't getting to the try/catch piece of code?

Comment: @JBKing Trying... :) http://i.imgur.com/vtOTGqX.png

Comment: What were the results of that? Is it still going into a black hole, is there an exception being caught or something else happening? Are there login credentials in the web.config or what identity is being used to access the DB here?

Comment: @JBKing Thank you.  I'm getting closer to debugging the problem.  It's a SqlException and I needed to catch it.  http://i.imgur.com/vrZTz5d.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the ideas from the comments above into an answer here:

This had to be put into a try/catch to notice the `SqlException` being thrown that was a connection issue.

```
    //code doesn't proceed past this line
    if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();
```